# how can I track products' expiry date with Barcode?

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, rsbarcodes

As far as my knowledge, product's barcode doesn't give any information regarding expiry date in this scenario, in my project I want to track the expiry date of a product without changing barcode frequently.

Comment: Why would you need to change the barcode frequently?

Comment: Thank you for comment. No, I Don't want to change barcode frequently but I need to track expiry date

Comment: That didn't answer my question at all.

Comment: ok, I should give an idea. As per my knowledge, we cannot frequently change the product's barcode and at the same time expiry date is belong to a batch no, in this condition how can we identify a product's expiry date from the barcode because product no (barcode)  is constant and the batch number is variable. This condition is quite difficult to track the expiry date. so I need a solution for that. I hope that my requirement is clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a specification called Application Identifier, which allows you to add expiration date information separately from product code, batch/lot number, etc.

This works with GS1-128, DataBar Expanded, GS1-DataMatrix, and GS1-QRCode.

If the combination is a product code, the product code does not need to be changed, and if it is a batch/lot number, the expiration date will be the same, so the combined value will not change, and if it changes, both will change.

See the following articles:
[GS1 AI (Application Identifier) & Element String Specification Reference](https://www.barcodefaq.com/barcode-properties/definitions/gs1-application-identifiers/)

> The GS1 Application Identifier (AI) appears after the Function Code 1 (FNC1) in [GS1-128](https://www.idautomation.com/barcode-faq/gs1-128/), [DataBar Expanded](https://www.idautomation.com/barcode-faq/gs1-databar/#GS1_DataBar_Expanded), [GS1-DataMatrix](https://www.idautomation.com/barcode-faq/2d/gs1-datamatrix/index.html) and [GS1-QRCode](https://www.idautomation.com/barcode-faq/2d/qr-code/aim-gs1-fnc1.html) barcode symbols to encode certain types of information. Multiple AIs may be encoded in a single symbol to allow, for example, serial numbers, sell-by dates and other information to be automatically evaluated at the point of sale.
>
> ```
>  GTIN-14                     01  14 numbers: 13 digits + MOD10 check digit
>  GTIN-14 of contained items  02  14 numbers: 13 digits + MOD10 check digit
>  Batch or Lot Number         10  Variable, up to 20 digits
>  Production Date             11  6 numbers: YYMMDD
>  Expiration Date             17  6 numbers: YYMMDD
> ```

And there is an article of such an application example.
[How to: Sell an Item with Automatic Discount Triggered by Expiration/Best Before Date](https://help.lscentral.lsretail.com/Content/LS%20Retail/Product%20Design/Barcodes/How%20to%20Sell%20an%20Item%20with%20Automatic%20Discount%20Triggered%20by%20Expiration%20Best%20Before%20Date.htm?tocpath=Retail%7CBackOffice%7CProduct%20Design%7CBarcodes%7C_____4)

Comment: Thank you, Let me check with my developer